# Imported countrieslist is empty

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, export

In Laravel 5.8 / vuejs 2.6 app I need use list of countries and I create file resources/js/helpers/countries.js
with content :

```
export const countriesList = [
    {
        "Code": "AF",
        "Name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    ...
    {
        "Code": "ZW",
        "Name": "Zimbabwe"
    }
]
```

and in vue file I make :

```
<template>

    <div class="page-content col-md-offset-3">
        countriesList:{{ countriesList }}
    </div>


</template>
<script>
    import {bus} from '../../../../app';
    import appMixin from '../../../../appMixin';

    import { getAdmindashApi, getUseAdmindashApi } from "./../../../../helpers/commonFuncs";  // resources/js/helpers/commonFuncs.js

    import { countriesList } from './../../../../../js/helpers/countries.js' // resources/js/helpers/countries.js


    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                ...
                countriesList : []
            }

        },
        name: 'PersonalDetails',


    }

</script>
```

But countriesList is empty and I do not see why?

Comment: your export `data` function specifically sets the `countriesList` to an empty array - try removing `: []` from that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined value in data as empty list `[]`.

```
  data: function () {
      return {
          ...
          countriesList : [] // this will make the array as empty
      }
  },
```

Just remove `[]` and it will be like `countriesList: countriesList`.

```
  data: function () {
      return {
          ...
          countriesList // => countriesList: countriesList
      }
  },
```